# Common search terms used with Google Search Appliance API?

Tags: google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I know you can run a report to get this information, but is there a way to get "common" or "top" searches performed with the Google Search Appliance via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no.  The Administrative API of the Google Search Appliance gives you the ability to create the report data and you can also have the logs automatically being dumped to a SysLog server where you could then create a process to report on the log data (and generate the top queries).